# Groovy map (with array position of item) to json list of objects

Tags: json, list, dictionary, object, groovy

**Input :**

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
new JsonBuilder([test: 'test', test2: 'test2']).toPrettyString()
```

**or**

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson([test: 'test', test2: 'test2']))
```

**Output :**

```json
{
   "test" : "test",
   "test2" : "test2"
}
```

But how I will process the following in groovy language?

**Input :**

```
[test : 'test', testing[0].T1_Id : 'test1', testing[1].T2_Id : 'test2']
```

**Output :**

```json
{
   "test" : "test",
   "testing" : [
      {
         "T1_Id" : "test1"
      },
      {
         "T2_Id" : "test2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your Groovy input includes references to a variable named `testing`.  What type of object is that?

Comment: You can say testing as an item of the map which can be compared as an array , here the first index of that array is also a map "T1_Id" : "test1" and second index is also another map "T2_Id" : "test2"

Comment: The input spelled out in your requirements is `[test : 'test', testing[0].T1_Id : 'test1', testing[1].T2_Id : 'test2']`.  That code is not valid unless `testing` evaluates to something and whatever that something is needs to be able to respond to property requests for `T1_Id` and `T2_Id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def data = [
   "test" : "test",
   "testing" : [
      [
         "T1_Id" : "test1"
      ],
      [
         "T2_Id" : "test2"
      ]
   ]
]
new JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString()
```

should return you the desired json